Memory Error Python при определении кодировки
Писал код который ищет значения заданные пользователем в csv файле но была проблема разных кодировок и я изменил скрипт теперь MemoryError как это починить
Код:
import os
import csv
import chardet

choose = input('тест:')

if choose == '1':
    number = input('Введи номер телефона (Например: 7XXXXXXXXXX):')
    print('Поиск займет от 5 до 10 минут...')
    
    os.chdir('bd')
    os.chdir('numbers')
    
    def search_in_csv(result, search_term):
        count = 0
        found_rows = []
        
        with open(result, 'rb') as csvfile:
            data = csvfile.read()
            encoding = chardet.detect(data)['encoding']
        
        with open(result, newline='', encoding=encoding) as csvfile:
            csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
            for row in csvreader:
                found = False
                for value in row:
                    if search_term.lower() in value.lower():
                        found = True
                        break
                if found:
                    count += 1
                    found_rows.append(row)
        
        print(f"Количество совпадений: {count}")
        for row in found_rows:
            print(*row, sep='|')
    
    for name in 'GetContact_2021_59kk', 'part2':
        format_bd = 'csv'
        delimiters = '.'
        result = name + delimiters + format_bd
        search_term = number
        search_in_csv(result, search_term)


Могу предположить, что 59kk в суффиксе файла значит 59 миллионов записей. Файл немаленький. А вы его сразу весь в память грузите. И второе место, где могла возникнуть такая ошибка, это массив found_rows. Если будет слишком много совпадений, то массив тоже может вызвать недостаток свободного места. Однако первый вариант гораздо более вероятен.

Если вы постоянно обрабатываете одни и те же файлы, то не нужно каждый раз определять кодировку. Достаточно сделать это один раз, а в программе просто указывать нужную кодировку. И вообще, возьмите нормальную бд. "Поиск займет от 5 до 10 минут" - не есть хорошо.

@Стас бд большие поэтому такой поиск, как тогда можно от этого избавиться?

@Стас и впринипе как оптимизировать код

Нет, проблема не в размере) 59 миллионов записей для единовременной загрузки в память это много. А для поиска - нет. Просто то, что вы называете базой данных, на самом деле просто csv-таблица. И конечно, поиск перебором в ней занимает много времени. В настоящей базе данных есть возможность организовать данные так, чтобы это было оптимально для поиска. В этом деле я не специалист, поэтому механизмы хранения данных в бд изложить не смогу. Но поиск по ним в подавляющем большинстве случаем организован эффективнее, чем полным перебором.

Как сделать оптимальнее? Возьмите что-нибудь вроде MySql. Самым простым методом будет выделить номера телефонов в целые числа и составить в бд таблицу вида phoneNumber : Int -> payload : data_type. Где payload это информация из вашей текущей таблицы, связанная с номером телефона. Тип данных для него выберите сами, в зависимости от того, что там будет храниться. Теперь можно сделать выборку по нужному номеру телефона и вам вернется несколько payload, которые подошли под данный номер - это и будут результаты поиска.
